# Matching partial cases to Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, mapping, ipython

At first glance I thought this to be a simple issue yet I cannot find an answer that accurately fits...

I have a dictionary of state names and abbreviations like so;

```
{(' ak', ',ak', ', ak', 'juneau', ',alaska', ', alaska'): 'alaska',
 (' al', ',al', ', al', 'montgomery', ',alabama', ', alabama'): 'alabama',
 (' ar', ',ar', ', ar', 'little rock', ',arkansas', ', arkansas'): 'arkansas',
 (' az', ',az', ', az', 'phoenix', ',arizona', ', arizona'): 'arizona',
```

I am attempting to map this dictionary over various cases of self reported Twitter location that I have in a pandas dataframe to look for partial matches. For example, if one case read 'anchorage,ak' it would change the value to Alaska. I could see this being quite simple if it were a list, yet there must be another way to do this without looping. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the keys in your string always comma-separated? What output would you expect for the string `'anchorage,ak,al'`? Also, what do you mean by "change the value"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thats a fair point, I'm not sure what that output would be. Could it return the first successful match, in that case ',ak' to Alaska? By change the value I mean changing the case to match the dictionary value.

Comment: I think with the current layout of your dictionary, you won't get away without looping (why would a loop be a bad thing?) - but have you considered structuring your dictionary like this: `{' ak' : 'alaska', ',ak' : 'alaska', ', ak' : 'alaska', ...}`? Then you'd simply `split` your string by comma and look whether one of the results is in your dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think timgeb has the right idea above.  I would add two things:

1) You can also remove all whitespace from the given case before processing-- thus, there will be no need to include `' ak'`, `',ak'`, and `', ak'` all as keys-- a simple `'ak'` key would suffice.

2) Instead of repeating the state values in the dictionary, I would create an extra hash from integers to states i.e. `{0: 'alaska, 1: 'alabama' ...}` and store the corresponding integer key in your original dictionary.

Thus your resulting dictionary should look something like this:

```
A = {'ak': 0, 'juneau': 0, 'alaska': 0, 'al': 1, 'montgomery': 1, 'alabama': 1, ...}
```

And to access state names from integer values, you should have another dictionary like this for all 50 states:

```
B = {0: 'alaska', 1: 'alabama',  ...}
```

so given a case...

```
case = 'anchorage,ak'
case_list = case.replace(' ', '').split(',')  # remove all whitespace and split case by comma
for elem in case_list:
    if elem in A:
        # insert code to replace case with B[A[elem]]
        break
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly. I should've known to remove whitespace from case instead, duh. Oh well, thank you both!